# Uncaught SyntaxError in the JavaScript code

Tags: php, javascript, syntax-error

I have a syntax error which says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" and I think it is in the `<?php ?>` code in the JavaScript code, but can not figure out why... If I remove the code in the `<?php ?>` tag, I get no error. I had the error removed before, but then the error suddenly "turned" up again.

So here is the JavaScript functions. I am calling a PHP code because I need to display an error if something is not right, and that javascript function is being called from a PHP file. I am requiering the PHP file within this PHP file.

```
function visErrorFraaLastOppSjekk() {
    document.getElementById("errorLastOpp").innerHTML = "Filnamnet " + "<strong>" + "<?php echo substr($_FILES['file']['name'],0,50) ?>" + "</strong>" + "eksisterer allereide.<br>" + "Gje bilete eit anna namn, eller<br>" + "velg eit anna bilete og prøv igjen.";
}

  // Denne funksjonen er for last_opp_sjekk.php som tar med denne sida, index_geolocation, og setter inn tekst i error boks for last opp vindauget
function visErrorFraaLastOppOK() {
    document.getElementById("errorLastOpp").innerHTML = "Bilete er blitt opplasta.";
    document.getElementById("filNamnTabellR").value = "Opplasta_bilete/" + "<?php echo $_FILES['file']['name'] ?>"; // EDIT: FIXED
    document.getElementById("namnLastOpp").value = "<?php echo $_FILES['file']['name'] ?>";
    document.getElementById("storrelse_kb").value = "<?php echo round($_FILES['file']['size']/1024000, 3) ?>" + " megabyte " + "(<?php echo round($_FILES['file']['size']/1024, 3) ?>" + " kilobyte)";
}
```

Here is a picture of the error code:
[image]

[image]

**Update:**

Here is some more of the code in Google Developer Tools:

```
<script>
    // Denne funksjonen er for last_opp_sjekk.php som tar med denne sida, index_geolocation, og setter inn tekst i error boks for last opp vindauget
function visErrorFraaLastOppSjekk() {
    document.getElementById("errorLastOpp").innerHTML = "Filnamnet " + "<strong>" + "<br />
```

// The error code is on the line above
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\wamp\www\geolocation_for_voss_gymnas\index_geolocation_admin.php on line *103*
    Call Stack
    #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation
    10.0029204912{main}(  )..\index_geolocation_admin.php**:**0
    
    " + "
" + "eksisterer allereide." + "Gje bilete eit anna namn, eller
" + "velg eit anna bilete og prøv igjen.";
    }

```
  // Denne funksjonen er for last_opp_sjekk.php som tar med denne sida, index_geolocation, og setter inn tekst i error boks for last opp vindauget
function visErrorFraaLastOppOK() {
    document.getElementById("errorLastOpp").innerHTML = "Bilete er blitt opplasta.";
    document.getElementById("filNamnTabellR").value = "Opplasta_bilete/" + "<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\wamp\www\geolocation_for_voss_gymnas\index_geolocation_admin.php on line <i>109</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0029</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>204912</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\geolocation_for_voss_gymnas\index_geolocation_admin.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\index_geolocation_admin.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
</table></font>
";
    document.getElementById("namnLastOpp").value = "<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\wamp\www\geolocation_for_voss_gymnas\index_geolocation_admin.php on line <i>110</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0029</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>204912</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\geolocation_for_voss_gymnas\index_geolocation_admin.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\index_geolocation_admin.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
</table></font>
";
    document.getElementById("storrelse_kb").value = "<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\wamp\www\geolocation_for_voss_gymnas\index_geolocation_admin.php on line <i>111</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0029</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>204912</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\geolocation_for_voss_gymnas\index_geolocation_admin.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\index_geolocation_admin.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
</table></font>
0" + " megabyte " + "(<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\wamp\www\geolocation_for_voss_gymnas\index_geolocation_admin.php on line <i>111</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0029</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>204912</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\geolocation_for_voss_gymnas\index_geolocation_admin.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\index_geolocation_admin.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
</table></font>
0" + " kilobyte)";
}

  // Denne funksjonen er for last_opp_sjekk.php som tar med denne sida, index_geolocation, og setter inn tekst i error boks for last opp vindauget
function visErrorLastOppSjekkIV() {
    document.getElementById("errorLastOpp").innerHTML = "Fila er ikkje valid. Prøv igjen;<br>" + "sjekk filtypa og filstørrelsen.";
}
</script>
```

Comment: You should post the resulting JavaScript code, not the intermediate PHP code. Also, you should mark the line in which the error happens.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the error picture. Just a sec... :D

Comment: Please do not edit the solution into the question. _Post an answer_ and accept it!

Comment: Hehe, Ok; I will remember that if I post a new question and figure the answer out myself :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the problem in the following line:

```
document.getElementById("filNamnTabellR").value = "Opplasta_bilete/" + <?php echo $_FILES['file']['name'] ?>;
```

It is missing quotes around `<?php echo $_FILES['file']['name'] ?>` or should be:

```
document.getElementById("filNamnTabellR").value = "Opplasta_bilete/<?php echo $_FILES['file']['name'] ?>";
```

Note that for printing data from the server side, it is preferable to use `json_encode()` function.

---

**UPDATE:** You still have problems because `$_FILES['file']['name']` is undefined in PHP. The server side generates a warning, which is printed in several lines, while JavaScript does not support this type of multiline string literals. You have to check for `$_FILES` array element existence before printing.

Comment: Aha, Ok. Thank you. So the error will appear anyway then? Because everything works like I thought it should

Comment: @RVNOR Yeah, you just have a warning from server side. Remove the warning programmatically, and the problem will disappear.

Comment: Ok, cool. How do I remove the warning programmatically?

Comment: @RVNOR One simple way is to set `@` before `$_FILES['file']['name']`.

Comment: **Don't do this.** Fix the problem; don't obscure the warning.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That is *absolutely* true, besides we don't know what the resulting code should be. Overcoming the warning here means to check whether file was uploaded, and that mostly refers to the server side scripting and not to client side. However, sometimes local disabling of error reporting does a good trick.

Answer (score 1):

This line is culprit

```
document.getElementById("filNamnTabellR").value = "Opplasta_bilete/" + <?php echo $_FILES['file']['name'] ?>;
```

Replace it with

```
document.getElementById("filNamnTabellR").value = "Opplasta_bilete/" + "<?php echo $_FILES['file']['name'] ?>";
```

Comment: Thank you. Hmm.. I still get the error on line 32. I posted a picture of it

Comment: I noticed that there is <br/> added in yoir javascript code, that is might be due to an error/warning from server side. Before concatenating echo $_FILES['file']['name'], check whether it is set or not and this will clear the warning.

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
"Opplasta_bilete/" + <?php echo $_FILES['file']['name'] ?>;
```

to

```
"Opplasta_bilete/" + "<?php echo $_FILES['file']['name'] ?>";
```

Comment: You forgot to end the <br/> with `"`.It should be `"</strong><br/>"`.

Answer (score 1):

It's all those newlines. You're trying to cram a *huge* quantity of text into a JavaScript string without first sanitising it.

Comment: Hmm.. I have not been doing JavaScript for a long time, but how do I do that?

Comment: Now that you know the problem, I'll leave you to give it some thought for a few hours. Use your imagination!

Comment: Hehe, Ok. I will try to figure it out. :D

Comment: Do you mean to add `var Exampel = SomeCode/TextHere` ? And then add this varible in?

Comment: Something like this?: http://sraji.wordpress.com/2011/01/10/multiple-ways-to-concatenate-a-string-in-javascript/

Comment: @RVNOR: Possibly along those lines, yes.

Comment: Ok, so I tried doing it like this: `function visErrorFraaLastOppSjekk() {
var tekst1 = "Filnamnet " + "<strong>";
var tekstPHP1 = "<?php echo substr($_FILES['file']['name'],0,50) ?>";
var tekst2 = "</strong><br />" + "eksisterer allereide." + "Gje bilete eit anna namn, eller<br />" + "velg eit anna bilete og prøv igjen.";
var fullTekst = tekst1 + tekstPHP1 + tekst2;

 document.getElementById("errorLastOpp").innerHTML(fullTekst);`

But got the same error, can you tell me how to do it if you have any idea? :D

Comment: Is it an error that is not good to have? Because I can just use @ infront of `$_FILES`, as VisioN said, to remove the sytax error...

Comment: @PVNOR: Never obscure your code problems with `@`. You should basically never have `@` in your code being used like that. Fix the underlying symptom!

Comment: Yes, that could be bad; hehe. Hmm... I can't figure out what the underlying symptom is :S (I have not done this for a long time, hehe)
Updated the question.

Comment: I figured it out. It was not actually a problem, it was just that the PHP commands inside the JavaScript is only ran when a picture is uploaded, because then the user is redirected to another PHP page which is requiering the other PHP file again, and this is where the `<?php ?>` command(s) starts. I can't understand that I did not think about that before now, hehe.